# Permitido patentear uma arquitetura de software? (EUA)

Tags: arquitetura-de-software

Do mesmo modo que processo de transação fosse patenteada, porém mais amplo as funções de software com atividades humanas.

Pergunto, em relação ao EUA, já que no brasil não permite patende de software;

Comment: Já é complicado pra gente falar disto no Brasil porque nãos somos advogados. Falar sobre o que ocorre nos EUA será mais complicado ainda.

Comment: O lugar apropriado pra esta pergunta é em: http://law.stackexchange.com